# Convert column data to list in R

Tags: r

Below is the nested list that is framed manually. Similar to this, can we make a nested list for dataframe columns like shown below

```
nested_list = list(`East Coast` = list("NY", "NJ", "CT"),
           `West Coast` = list("WA", "OR", "CA"),
           `Midwest` = list("MN", "WI", "IA"))
```

Example

```
asd <- data.frame(Cat1 = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), Cat2 = c("x","y", "x1", "y1"))
```

Expected output

```
$`A`
$`A`[[1]]
[1] "x"

$`A`[[2]]
[1] "y"

$`B`
$`B`[[1]]
[1] "x1"

$`B`[[2]]
[1] "y1"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```r
lapply(split(asd[, -1], asd$Cat1), as.list)
```

```r
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] "x"

$A[[2]]
[1] "y"


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] "x1"

$B[[2]]
[1] "y1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Or convert to `list` first and then `split`

```
with(asd, split(as.list(Cat2), Cat1))
$A
$A[[1]]
[1] "x"

$A[[2]]
[1] "y"


$B
$B[[1]]
[1] "x1"

$B[[2]]
[1] "y1"
```